# ARM raspberry pi dockerize from Windows

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile, arm

I have a Python script that I need to run it on my Raspberry Pi 4.

My idea is to dockerize it, my first idea was doing

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

copy main.py .
copy requirements.txt .

run pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

but `FROM python:3` doesn't work on the Raspberry because it's not ARM.

Reading and asking chatgpt I found this options, `FROM arm32v7/python:3`, `FROM python:3-slim-stretch-arm32v7` and `FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster` but they always crash with this type of message,

```
> 2023/07/03 13:25:05 http2: server: error reading preface from client
> //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed [+] Building 0.8s
> (3/3) FINISHED                                                        
> docker:default  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile   
> 0.0s  => => transferring dockerfile: 326B                                                                                                                    0.0s   => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                       0.0s   => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s   => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3-slim-stretch-arm32v7                       
> 0.7s 
> ------
>  > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3-slim-stretch-arm32v7:
> ------ Dockerfile:1
> --------------------    1 | >>> FROM python:3-slim-stretch-arm32v7    2 |    3 |     WORKDIR /usr/src/app
> -------------------- ERROR: failed to solve: python:3-slim-stretch-arm32v7:
> docker.io/library/python:3-slim-stretch-arm32v7: not found
```

How can I dockerize my script and use it on my Raspberry 4?

I found [arm32v7/python](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/python) but or I'm doing wrong or is not working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: to clarify: you are trying to build on a windows host and than copy the Dockerfile to your raspberry and build again?

Comment: What I want is use my script coded on windows and run it on the Raspberry with same libraries

Comment: and why is it not working with the `python:3` tag on the raspbeerry? it should have an `arm` version.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand where this Problems come you will need a few more details on how docker operates:

Each docker image on docker-hub is build for a specific operating system and architecture. So your `arm32v7/python:3` will only work on ARM systems and `winamd64/python:3` will only work on windows.

This is of course rarely useful and situations like yours will often occur, where you what to run the same stuff on multiple systems and docker wants to solve this. Thats where **Shared Tags** come in.

#### Shared Tags

These are a collection of there tags (and therefore images) and allow docker to select the image fitting your system. So when you request `python:3.11` on windows docker will fetch the windows version of the image and the same on ARM. These are *not the same image* but they will work identically.

### Your Problem

So you did the exacly right thing and your `Dockerfile` should work on both your windows system and your raspberry pi. This leads me to believe that you have some other problem, maybe docker on the pi need an update?

To validate what architectures are available for a tag, you can run `docker manifest inspect python:3` on the raspberry and check if it gets older manifests that don't contain your required architecture.